# Quarkus CDI not working when creating a library

Tags: java, maven, cdi, quarkus

I have two projects A and B in project B and i want to injcet a CDI bean from project A however, this fails due too

> java.lang.RuntimeException: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
> [error]: Build step io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor#validate threw an exception: jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: jakarta.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type test.xml.filereader and qualifiers [@Default]
> - java member: org.acme.hibernate.orm.XmlResource#fileReader
> - declared on CLASS bean [types=[org.acme.hibernate.orm.XmlResource, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=org.acme.hibernate.orm.XmlResource]

Project A has a CDI bean like this

```java
@Slf4j
@ApplicationScoped
public class FileReader {

    @Inject
    Configuration configuration;

    public void testCDIInject() {
    }
    
}
```

project B wants to use this

```java
@Path("/test")
public class XmlResource {

  @Inject
  FileReader fileReader;

  @GET
  public String get() {
    fileReader.testCDIInject();
    return "asdf";
  }
}
```

for some reason i get the error above. why?

i install project A with `mvn clean install -U`

and have it in project Bs pom.xml

Comment: Does project A have the `beans.xml` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the related [Quarkus guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/maven-tooling)

> By default, Quarkus will not discover CDI beans inside another module.
> The best way to enable CDI bean discovery for a module in a multi-module project would be to include the `jandex-maven-plugin`, unless it is the main application module already configured with the quarkus-maven-plugin, in which case it will be indexed automatically.

In project A you should generate the jandex.idx like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-a</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<!-- dependencies and others... -->

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.smallrye</groupId>
                <artifactId>jandex-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-index</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jandex</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
<!-- Other plugin configurations e.q. quarkus-maven-plugin... -->

        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Now during `project B` build CDI bean which defined in `project A` will be available in `project B`. Just add `project A` as a dependency to `project B`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-b</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<!-- properties and managed dependencies -->

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>project-a</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- other  dependencies -->
    </dependencies>

    <!-- plugins, site configurations and so on -->
</project>
```

Comment: Either a typo or maybe I'm misunderstanding the solution, shouldn't the 2nd pom in the example reference project-a as a dependency instead of project-b?

Comment: @RobertNgetich nice catch, thank you. It was just a typo in the xml snipped. I've just fixed. Thanks again.